# Unity - Change color of particles over distance

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am trying to create a static grass area with particles and I've been trying to change the color of the particles depending how far are from the emitter, but I had no luck. (This is because I need the grass to look yellow in the far edges of the grass area).

If you can point me in the right direction or have some similar shaders I will really appreciate it.

Thanks!

PD: why I am doing grass with particles? Great question, I am experimenting in ways to make great performance grass area for Augmented Reality in mobile. If you know any other way, let me know!
[image]

Comment: Maybe [colorOverLifeTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysColorOverLifeModule.html) could help you?

Answer (score 2):

fortunately had someone helping me for this. If you wonder what worked: creating a C# script to know the distance from the emitter, then modify the particle shader and use the distance to create a fading to the new tint color variable. Used Amplify for this. If you have a similar problem do no hesitate to contact me. Sharing is caring.
[image]